# How to get distinct column with max value and limit, hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table emp with around 10 rows

```
empno,ename,dept,sal,deptno
```

now I want result as ename from each dept who as max sal.

EX:

```
12,ravi,manager,20000,10
43,hari,engineer,10000,20
32,sam,clerk,5000,30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the max salary for each dept and then get the ename for each max salary.

```
select ename,dept,sal
from emp
where sal in (select max(sal) as sal from emp group by dept)
```

Using `row_number()` and `partition`

```
select * from 
(
   select ename,dept,sal, row_number() over (partition by dept order by sal desc) as row_no
   from emp
) res 
where res.row_no = 1
```